# tofind.info search plugin cannot uninstall it from Chrome browser. Its a spyware as I never installed this. Can't find anything about it on google

Tags: google-chrome, browser, spyware

Google Chrome showed me this message a small div kind of popup.
The upgrade completed successfully.
Google Chrome has successfully upgraded your extension with the new ToFind service.
 Continue using toFind services
learn more

I don't know when this got installed I never installed anything during this period

I remember installing a software that installed the superfish search plugin(again without my knowledge).
Neither did Kaspersky detect it nor did Google Chrome give any warning.

I managed to uninstall it. But I still get the "find product" button on certain shopping website but I don't see any results.

Now this has come up in the last few days when I had installed no knew software.

I think Google Chrome is vulnerable to this spyware/spamware.
Don't even know what is is

Anybody seen this and know how to uninstall it.
It does not show up in the extensions. I have just a handfull of extensions

Comment: This seems to be embedded within extensions.  I found removing a WhoIS extension resulted in removal of the unwanted search bar.

Answer (score 2):

Gone through a lot of research basically found nothing on the web, after reviewing all programs installed and extensions for "ToFind" which gives no result.. and as suggested above removed all search engines (except google) from Chrome I still get the annoying floating search thingee on all http pages.

Went on and review the site tofind.info, where the search's setting is pointing to, which reveals a bit more info:
"...The "To Find" functionalities are added by browser add-ons and are available directly using "To Find" add-ons or by partners that publish their add-ons combined with the "To Find" functionalities to their add-ons as addition to their functionalities."

Now Im pretty sure this is something to do with the extensions I have, which may have been bundled with this service.

Once I get to this it doesn't take long for me to pinpoint it by disabling and enabling extensions... for me, it is the "BarDeCo: QR Code Decoder & Encoder/Generator 1.0.0.8" which I need to disable and remove that icon. The thing is, I had this extension for ages, but just recently this search thing pops up.. so it is a bit of annoying and is revealing some weakness in the control Chrome has on its extensions, it doesn't tell user what has changed (like android or iphone apps).

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: QR was the culprit on my machine also.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed my search engines in Chrome settings and removed Live Search, Yahoo, and Ask.com from my default search engines, and the "toFind" button disappeared.

I didn't check after doing each one, so I don't know which was the culprit.

I left Bing and Google.

You can find them here: chrome://settings/searchEngines